# Approximating a probability density with a point set

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, probability-distributions, approximation-theory, numerical-integration

Let $f$ be a "nice" probability density on $\mathbb{R}^2$, let $p=1/k$ for some fixed positive integer $k$, and let $\epsilon>0$.  Are there any known statements of the following form?

"There exists a point set $Q$ of size $n = n(\epsilon)$ such that for every convex subset $C$ that satisfies $|C\cap Q| = pn$, we have $\left| \int_C f(x)~dx - p\right|\leq \epsilon$."

I think it is clear that $n$ would also depend on Lipschitz constants associated with $f$, or its support region, in addition to $\epsilon$, but I cannot find a reference to such statements.  I would assume that $n=O(1/\epsilon^2)$ based on basic dimensional intuition, but cannot justify such a claim.

Comment: I'm not an expert so I'll just leave a comment, but "On the Discrepancy of Convex Plane Sets" by Beck and "Convergence Rates for the Isotrope Discrepancy" by Stute might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @JasonGaitonde I'm obviously not an expert either, but that certainly looks like an answer to me! If you submit as such I will gladly accept it. Thanks!